# Get-ADGroupMember and extensionAttribute5 of the members

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I'm writ some script and he works until the moment that I trying to do export to the file.
after this, I have a mistake-"cmdlet Export-Csv at command pipeline position 1"
Am I doing something wrong? I'm a beginner in PowerShell and scripting in general. Thanks in advance.

```
 Get-ADGroupMember -Recursive ‘MFA - Users’ | ForEach {Get-ADUser -filter {SamAccountName -eq $_.SamAccountName} -Properties extensionAttribute5 ,employeeid} | Format-Table -Property  name ,extensionAttribute5 ,SamAccountName ,employeeid



Export-CSV -path "$home\desktop\out-ADGroupMember.csv"
```

Comment: `Format-Table` should be used for display purposes only as with other `Format-*` commands. It should not be used for further processing. If you want to send to `Export-Csv`, then don't `Format-Table` first. When using `Export-Csv`, you need to provide it an input object first. Otherwise, it has no data to output.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you are sending no data or objects to your `Export-Csv` command. You will need to do something like the following:

```
Get-ADGroupMember -Recursive 'MFA - Users' | ForEach {
    Get-ADUser -filter "SamAccountName -eq '$_.SamAccountName'" -Properties extensionAttribute5 ,employeeid
} | Export-Csv -Path "$home\desktop\out-ADGroupMember.csv" -NoType
```

---

If you look at the command info for `Export-Csv`, you will notice that `-InputObject` is required because it is a parameter not contained with a set of `[]`. The documentation for [Export-Csv](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv?view=powershell-7) shows that the `InputObject` parameter can accept a pipeline value. This means you can either pipe an object into the command or pass it directly to the parameter.

```
# Show command info
Get-Command Export-Csv -Syntax
Export-Csv [[-Path] <string>] [[-Delimiter] <char>] -InputObject <psobject> [-LiteralPath <string>] [-Force] [-NoClobber
] [-Encoding <string>] [-Append] [-NoTypeInformation] [-WhatIf] [-Confirm] [<CommonParameters>]

Export-Csv [[-Path] <string>] -InputObject <psobject> [-LiteralPath <string>] [-Force] [-NoClobber] [-Encoding <string>]
 [-Append] [-UseCulture] [-NoTypeInformation] [-WhatIf] [-Confirm] [<CommonParameters>]

# Using pipeline
$data | Export-Csv -Path file.csv -NoType

# Using named parameter
$data | foreach { Export-Csv -InputObject $_ -Path file.csv -Append -NoType}
```

---

As an aside, `Format-*` commands should only be used for display purposes. If you are planning to process the output beyond just viewing it in the console, you should not pipe into `Format-*` at that time.

```
# Good practice
Get-ADGroupMember 'MFA - Users' | Format-Table
$users = Get-ADGroupMember 'MFA - Users'
$users | Export-Csv file.csv -NoType
$users | Format-Table

# Bad practice
Get-ADGroupMember 'MFA - Users' | Format-Table | Select SamAccountName
$users = Get-ADGroupMember 'MFA - Users' | Format-Table
$users | Export-Csv file.csv -NoType
```